# How are Ansible templates evaluated? What does it mean that they are "recursively evaluated"?

Tags: ansible, escaping

> Using raw/endraw in Jinja2 will not work as you expect because templates in Ansible are recursively evaluated.
>
> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#notes
>  "Last updated on Aug 15, 2019".  Applies to Ansible 2.8.

What does the documentation mean by "recursively evaluated"? It sounds very scary. Are the implications specific to `{% raw %}` / `{% endraw %}`, or are there other implications?

Answer (score 0):

> As long as the templates will evaluate, they will evaluate recursively to allow variable nesting.
>
> As a result, if the template changes it will keep going.
>
> I think we just need to document this and not suggest raw/endraw.
>
> -- [Comment on issue #4638, "Using {% raw %} in templates does not stop jinja2 variable substitution"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4638#issuecomment-26928000)

This appears to have changed at some point.  If I try to run the reproducer in the linked issue on Ansible 2.8, raw/endraw work as expected.

I reported this as a mistake in the documentation: [#61233 Template action does not recursively evaluate variables any more](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/61233).  It turns out:

> things are mixed here, [your report is talking about] the 'template' action and not 'templates in ansible' which is different in how they are handled, but there does seem to be a behaviour change in the action.

I can see that "templates in ansible" are evaluated recursively, in some sense (Ansible 2.8.4):

`$ ansible -m debug localhost -a msg='{{ a }}' -e 'a={{ b }}' -e 'b={{ a }}'`

`localhost | FAILED! => {`
`"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ b }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ a }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ b }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message:` ... `An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ b }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ a }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: recursive loop detected in template string: {{ a }}"`

So this looks different to an imperative programming language, like Python or Javascript.

My concern was this was implemented by re-templating the output string, until it did not contain `{{`.  This would be a terrifying use of in-band signalling.

As far as I can tell in the version I am currently using, this is not the case.  I.e. Ansible now appears to correctly implement a [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) model.

`$ ansible -m debug localhost -a msg='{{ a }}' -e 'a={{ "{{ 1 }}" }}'`

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "{{ 1 }}"
}
```